# AVL tree deletion c++

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I am having problems with deleting an element in my AVL tree.

Here is my deletion function

```
template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
bool  AvlTree <TYPE, KTYPE> :: AVL_Delete (KTYPE  dltKey)
{
//  Local Definitions 
    bool shorter;
    bool success;

    NODE<TYPE>  *newRoot;

//  Statements 
    newRoot = _delete (tree, dltKey, shorter, success);
    if (success)
       {
        tree = newRoot;
        count--;
       } // if 
    return success;
}   // AVL_Delete

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
NODE<TYPE>*  AvlTree<TYPE,  KTYPE> 
          :: _delete (NODE<TYPE> *root, 
                      KTYPE       dltKey,
                      bool&       shorter,
                      bool&       success) 
{
//  Local Definitions 
    NODE<TYPE> *dltPtr;
    NODE<TYPE> *exchPtr;
    NODE<TYPE> *newRoot;

//  Statements 
    if (!root)
       {
        shorter = false;
        success = false;
        return NULL;
       } //  if -- base case 

    if (dltKey < root->data.key)
        {
         root->left = _delete (root->left, dltKey, 
                               shorter,    success);
         if (shorter)
             root   = dltRightBalance (root, shorter);
        } // if less 
    else if (dltKey > root->data.key)
        {
         root->right = _delete (root->right, dltKey,
                                shorter,     success);
         if (shorter)
             root = dltLeftBalance (root, shorter);
        } //  if greater 
    else
        //  Found equal node 
        {
         dltPtr  = root;
         if (!root->right)
             // Only left subtree 
             {
              newRoot  = root->left;
              success  = true;
              shorter  = true;
              delete (dltPtr);
              return newRoot;            //  base case 
             } //  if true 
         else
             if (!root->left)
                 //  Only right subtree 
                 {
                  newRoot  = root->right;
                  success  = true;
                  shorter  = true;
                  delete (dltPtr);
                  return newRoot;        // base case 
                } //  if 
             else
                 //  Delete NODE has two subtrees 
                 {
                  exchPtr = root->left;
                  while (exchPtr->right)
                      exchPtr = exchPtr->right;

                  root->data = exchPtr->data;
                  root->left = _delete (root->left, 
                                        exchPtr->data.key,
                                        shorter, 
                                        success); 
                  if (shorter)
                      root = dltRightBalance (root, shorter); 
                 } //  else 

        } // equal node 
    return root; 
}   // _delete
```

And this is what i am trying to achieve

```
for (int loop=0;loop<newIdea.size();loop++)
    {
     for (int j = 0; j < newIdea[loop].getKeyword().size(); j++) {
                key = newIdea[loop].getKeyword()[j];

                Index modIndex;
                if (tree.AVL_Retrieve(key, modIndex)){
                    for (int i = 0; i < modIndex.idList.size(); i++) {
                        if (ID == modIndex.idList[i]){
                            modIndex.idList.erase(modIndex.idList.begin()+i);
                            tree.AVL_Delete(modIndex);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

this is the error i am getting

> [Error] no matching function for call to 'AvlTree >::AVL_Delete(Index&)'

this is my struct to insert into my tree which works

```
struct Index {
string key;
vector<int> idList;
};
```

where key represents a word and idList represents a integer ID where the word was located.
my code above is meant to search the tree for the word, remove it from the Idlist in my struct and then remove that instance of the word and ID from my AVL tree.

Comment: How do you declare `tree`? Is there more than one variable by that name? It looks as if it could be a local variable, global, member, or all three.

Comment: @Beta only one variable by that name and it is declared as 
AvlTree<Index, string> tree;

Comment: Then its `AVL_Delete` will take a `string` as its argument; there is no `AVL_Delete(Index)`. Perhaps you meant `tree.AVL_Delete(modIndex.key);`

Comment: @Beta i have tried that except it still doesnt delete anything

Comment: There isn't enough information in your post to reveal the source of the problem, and most of the code you posted appears to have no bearing on it. Please look over our [intro section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with special attention to the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i didnt want to post too much code as i thought it would result in negative reviews of my question. What else should i include?
i have inserted a copy of my delete function and a copy of my function in where i use the delete function, what else is needed?